# Passing a reference to a variable

Tags: c++, mfc

I get an error `stack around variable dlgFile is corrupted` which I am trying to fix. This is legacy code and it looks dubious. I replaced part of in another project which is here:

```
void CPlantDlg::OnBnClickedButtonTestReference()
{
    CString str = _T("Hello string");

    { // intentional so destructor of Tester is called below
        Tester tester( str );
    }

    AfxMessageBox (str );
}
```

The Tester class is:

```
class Tester
{
public:
    Tester(CString & str);
    ~Tester(void);

    CString _str;
};

Tester::Tester(CString & str) : _str( str )
{

}

Tester::~Tester(void)
{
    //_str = "Changed"; // say I do this, what will be printed in caller function?
}
```

Is passing of the CString safe this way? I think the `Tester` class should destroy its `_str` which should result in getting the original str destroyed outside the class?

When I run it does prompt "Hello String" though.

If I enable `_str = "Changed"` what will you expect to prompt? It actually still shows the original string. It was passed by reference, why is that?

Comment: Can you please show the declaration of your Tester class.

Comment: @Kik added to the post

Comment: "Hello string" is to be expected since `Tester::_str` will be a *copy* of whatever the constructor receives. I don't see anything in the posted code that explains the memory corruption error.

Comment: It is passed to the function by reference, but then it is copied to `_str`

Comment: You have mentioned two separate problems. You have not posted any code that even references a variable named `dlgFile` so we can't even begin to help you with your first problem. Your second problem has already been answered correctly, but you shouldn't use a destructor to set the values of an object's member variables that you plan on accessing later. The object will be destroyed at that point and you will not have access to that member variable anymore.

Comment: CString is automatically reference counted, so you gain nothing by passing it as a reference.  Although, if for some reason you do want to pass it as a reference anyway, it should be a const reference in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The _str variable in your Tester class is an instance of a CString object.  When the member initializer says

```
_str( str )
```

it is not storing a reference to the CString reference that is passed to the constructor, the copy constructor is being called, and _str is initialized with the same value as str.  It is just a copy.  So changing it will not have an effect on the original CString.

Comment: What if the constructor was `_str = str` instead of member initializer list. I guess still copy constructor will be called?

Comment: In that case the operator= would be called, but to the same effect.  The point is that your class member _str is an instance of CString, not a reference or pointer.